# Is it possible to indicate a maximum waiting time before closing a TWILIO room created by REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, twilio

I've read this in Twilio doc(https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks):

[image: Twilio documentation]

I'm using Twilio library to create rooms from a loopback backend. And I wonder if it's possible  to change this number when I create the class? There is any option to do this and maybe reduce this waiting time and close the room after, for example, 1 minute?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way to set the timeout for the room ended event like that, it is 5 minutes. You can see [the supported parameters that you can use when creating a video room in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-parameters).

If you wanted to close up the room manually once everyone has left it, you could watch the `participant-disconnected` status callbacks and then trigger an [update to complete the room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#complete-room) once you are happy that it is finally empty.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I thought, but I wanted to be sure that I wasn't missing anything in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it's possible using the property `empty_room_timeout` and `unused_room_timeout`.

Reference:

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#rooms-list-resource